# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on a non-object in... comparing DateTime from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime

Im trying to compare two different DateTime and get the difference.

Im getting this error PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function diff() on a non-object in... when trying to run/compile my code but cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$localhost = "localhost";
$conn = mysqli_connect($localhost, $mysqlUsername, $mysqlPassword, $mysqlDB);

if (!$conn)
{
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        echo "Connection to DB failed";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM UniqueUsers";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0 )
{
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
                $datetime1 = new DateTime($row['worldtime']);
                $interval = $datetime->diff($datetime1);
                echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
        }
}
```

Comment: This means that it's impossible to create `DateTime` from your `$row['worldtime']`

Comment: Your $datetime variable is not an object.

Comment: Would be interesting to see the content of `$row['worldtime']`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `$datetime` variable is not an object. Function **[date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)** doesn't return a DateTime object, but a formatted string.

Replace your first line with

```
$datetime = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

Comment: or just `new DateTime;`. `date` uses "now" by default, as does `DateTime`, `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` is like calling `(new DateTime)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`